# RegularExpression validation not working on model

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
public class Register
{
[RegularExpression(@"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$", ErrorMessage = "eMail is not in proper format")]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="Name Required"), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages))]
public string Email{ get; set; }
}
```

Email that i tried: asd@asd.com is valid but it fail the validation.

The required is working, but the regular expression is failing. Even if I enter a valid email address, it will still say that email is not in proper format.

Anything I missed here? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This regex validator is working on my other mvc application by using Resources.resx. So I think what is wrong here is how I declared it on my model class.

Comment: Provide some sample input. Your regex will pass test@test.com but fail t.est@test.com.

Comment: Your regex will fail "some.one@some.thing.travel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. I accidentally put the wrong regex on my code:

```
"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$
```

instead of:

```
 @"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$
```

Now I will focus on to make the best email regex. Thanks!

Comment: Just what is stated above, I will edit to create a new regex to pass all valid email. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @Gerald: This might be relevant - http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|"
        + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)"
        + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$");
```

/* declare in public and validate for your mail text box */